# axios parallel requests parsing a dataTable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables, axios

I've got a dataTables table with accounting data. The purpose is to send the row id to a php script which manages the accounting transfer via SAP and returns a reference number or an error text which should be inserted in the last column. This is working, but in the current version it is done by jQuery ajax in sequential, blocking order which takes it's time. My next attempt to made it quicker is done with axios and I was asking myself, if this is the correct (parallel) way? (I am new to these promises.)

```
for (var i = 0; i < table.rows().count(); i++) {
    rowData = table.row(i).data();
    axios.post('/test/data', rowData).then(function(response){
        addResultToRow(response);
        // promises.push(axios.post('/test/data', rowData));
    });
}

function addResultToRow(response){
    rowData = table.row('#'+response.data.id).data();
    rowData.result = response.data.result;
    table.row('#'+response.data.id).data(rowData);
    table.draw();
}
```

I am thinking, that the request has to take place in the loop, but the ".then" call should be outside. Isn't that construct above blocking the loop until the response is received? I also tried the axios.all() way, but that is displaying all results, when the last response was received:

```
axios.all(promises).then(function(results) {
    results.forEach(function(response) {
        addResultToRow(response);
    });
}).catch(function(error){
    console.error(error);
});
```

## Edit:

Maybe it is a better way to push all requests into an array:

```
for (var i = 0; i < table.rows().count(); i++) {
    rowData = table.row(i).data();
    requests.push(
        axios.post('/api/test/data', rowData)
            .then(function(response){
                addResultToRow(response);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            })
    );
}

function addResultToRow(response){
    rowData = table.row('#'+response.data.id).data();
    rowData.result = response.data.result;
    table.row('#'+response.data.id).data(rowData);
    if (response.data.status === true) {
        $(table.row('#'+response.data.id).node()).addClass('success');
        updateProgressBar();
    } else {
        $(table.row('#'+response.data.id).node()).addClass('danger');
        updateProgressBar();
    }
    table.draw();
}
```

Works well. Your thoughts?

Comment: Promises are not parallel, they are sequential, that is the purpose of them.  If it does not matter what order they are done in, I would consider flagging a row at the beginning of the transaction to prevent more than one transaction at a time, then unflag them when transaction is done.  That way, you can spin off ajax call as needed.

Comment: I think the `axios.all` is the best approach. Specially because you are using a shared variable `table`. You could run into race conditions if you make it non sequential.

Comment: `axios.all` will not give the user any visual progress. My code above is working as expected. It fires one row after another and is inserting the responses in the order they are received. So if line 3 takes longer, line 4 is not blocked. Is every call to axios.post() in the loop a new instance in memory and the response will go to the sender or is the same instance receiving all different responses?